# PHPUNIT error when running tests with PHPSTORM

Tags: php

Running phpunit tests using PhpStorm.

Receiving this error:

> /usr/local/php5/bin/php
>   /private/var/folders/m8/k61mmmmj7g732j3pd0_91s0c0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php
>   --configuration /Users/psteinheuser/unity/test/phpunit.xml DatabaseDumperTest
>   /Users/psteinheuser/unity/test/DatabaseDumperTest.inc Testing started
>   at 11:36 AM ...
>
> Fatal error: Class IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener contains 1
>   abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest)
>   in
>   /private/var/folders/m8/k61mmmmj7g732j3pd0_91s0c0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php
>   on line 504
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0013     340096   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/m8/k61mmmmj7g732j3pd0_91s0c0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener contains 1
>   abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest)
>   in
>   /private/var/folders/m8/k61mmmmj7g732j3pd0_91s0c0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php
>   on line 504

Have found previous posts which have said this is fixed, though I seem to have the correct versions where it should work.

PHPStorm 7.1.3
phpunit  3.7.28
php 5.4.24

The OS is Mac 10.9.2

Have removed and re-installed PHPStorm, upgraded php, re-installed phpunit, restarted apache, rebooted, scratched my head, etc.

Running the phpunit tests manually from the terminal, works fine.

Looking at Preferences within PHpStorm, it seems to be pointing to phpunit correctly.
I'm thinking it's a permission or path issue, but I don't know where to look next.

Appreciate any input or direction.

Comment: I've documented a workaround here:

[IntelliJ IDEA won't run PHPUnit 4.0 tests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22799620/315988)

Answer (score 2):

In PHPStorm, the only way I was able to solve this was by manually updating the contents of the jar file where this error exists.

We're both on Mac OSX 10.9, so these instructions should work for you.

Begin by making a copy of the existing jar file:

`cp /Applications/PhpStorm.app/plugins/php/lib/php.jar /Applications/PhpStorm.app/plugins/php/lib/php.jar.orig`

Now, create a temporary directory to hold your jar file's contents and extract

`mkdir ~/jarfiles
cd ~/jarfiles
jar xf /Applications/PhpStorm.app/plugins/php/lib/php.jar`

Once extracted, you'll need to edit the phpunit.php file to add the missing method stub

`vi scripts/phpunit.php`

Around line 310 in my file is a class 'IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener'. Insert the following method stub:

public function addRiskyTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time){}

Now just re-pack your jar and replace it into your PhpStorm:

`jar cf0 php.jar ./*
mv php.jar /Applications/PhpStorm.app/plugins/php/lib/php.jar`

That fixed it for me. Hope it fixes it for you too. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Worked absolutely perfectly for for phpunit 4.0.7 and Phpstorm on osx.